# Taking picture and geotag it in android

Tags: android, geotagging

I have to make an app to take a picture and showing **geotag** on it.

Even the captured image from camera or gallery has to show **geotag** on it for this requirement I searched a lot but I did not find any solution.

Can some one help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can u explain more about it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a class for reading and writing Exif tags in a JPEG file or a RAW image file.Supported formats are: JPEG, DNG, CR2, NEF, NRW, ARW, RW2, ORF, PEF, SRW and RAF.

You can use `ExifInterface` to get metadata of any image and you can edit also.
For more details [check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)